# How to replace all 0 values to NA but only in a part of data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I want to replace all 0 values to NA but only in subset of columns.

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(100,sample(0:9,1000,rep=TRUE)))
```

To change all 0 to NA in the entire df one should use

```
df[df == 0] <- NA
```

but I want to change 0 to NA only in subset of columns 5:100, I have tried

```
df[df == 0][ , 5:100] <- NA
```

```
df[df == 0][5:100] <- NA
```

```
df[ , 5:100][df == 0] <- NA
df[5:100][df == 0] <- NA
df[5:100][df[5:1000] == 0] <- NA
df[df[5:1000] == 0] <- NA
df[which(df[, 5:100] == 0)] <- NA
df[which(df[5:100] == 0)] <- NA
```

but all of that returns an error.

How to apply the operation to part of the df?

Comment: I had that but with a mistake (put 1000 instead of 100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the subsetting on both `df` calls:

```r
df[5:100][df[5:100] == 0] <- NA
```

Take this smaller example:

```r
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(replicate(3,sample(0:9,10,rep=TRUE)))
df[2:3][df[2:3] == 0] <- NA

   X1 X2 X3
1   8  4  4
2   3  9  4
3   6  5  1
4   0  9  9
5   1  6  8
6   6  8 NA
7   1  4  3
8   2  4  2
9   0  8  5
10  4  8  9
```

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` option using `across` and `replace` like this:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(100,sample(0:9,1000,rep=TRUE)))

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(5:100, ~ replace(.x, .x == 0, NA)))
```